# How to select table by column value in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to select table by column value?

For example:

member

```
id | user_id | belong_to
 1 |       1 |         a
 2 |       3 |         b
 3 |       1 |         b
 4 |       2 |         c
           .
           .
           .
```

a_user

```
id | name
 1 | Cindy
 2 | Jack
 3 | Kenny
   .
   .
   .
```

b_user

```
id | name
 1 | Ted
 2 | Janne
 3 | Ben
   .
   .
   .
```

c_user

```
id | name
 1 | Owen
 2 | Nancy
 3 | Leon
   .
   .
   .
```

.
  .
  .

Table prefix name is unknow and can only get from member.belong_to.

When I query

```
SELECT m.id, u.name from member m
LEFT JOIN $(member.belong_to)_user u 
ON m.user_id=u.id
```

The table will be:

```
id | name
 1 | Cindy
 2 | Ben
 3 | Ted
 4 | Nancy
   .
   .
   .
```

Is it possible to do like $(member.belong_to) part?

Comment: In SQL, tables names are not dynamic, you don't dynamically provide table names in queries. That's why we have rows. Your data model is designed incorrectly. There's no reason why your tables should be named `b_user` or `a_user` if you can create one table that contains `user_id, belongs_to_id`.

Comment: @Mjh Because it's design for multitenant. So they use prefix name to distinguish.

Comment: The reason you've got is, sadly, irrelevant - the design goes against relational algebra. You can always distinguish between tenants with `tenant_id` field in your tables. What you have now doesn't allow itself to be queried. I'm sorry but that's not the way SQL is meant to be used. Good luck.

Comment: you cannot do this in pure SQL you can do this build dinamic sql  .. alias   creating server side the query string you need  and then  execute ..

Comment: @Mjh Thanks I got it. It's hard to combine all in one table. That will change lots of code. And query time will be slower. So it will need to add some index or something. I don't think I can handle it by myself.

Comment: That's why it's important to start with proper design. Queries won't be slower, I'm not sure why you think they would. Worst case scenario is that they run as they did so far. Bear in mind that creating multiple tables doesn't mean MySQL uses disk or RAM in a different way, it's likely that your system would be faster if it's designed properly.

Comment: @scaisEdge dynamic sql? Thanks I'll take a look at is.

Comment: @Mjh As I know when there is lots of data in one table.The table query time will be slow and add index will fix it.In other system it may use view to save data in RAM.Maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: MySQL doesn't really work the way you imagined - whether there's 1 table or 50 tables, data is saved to the same file on the disk and amount of RAM allocated doesn't depend on number of tables but on data size. The data can be in one table or 50 tables, it's not important. That means if you create multiple tables to optimize your system - it's not going to do anything, except complicate the system for you to use (as it has). Query time depends on multiple factors, index is not magic and it doesn't "fix" everything. That's why it's important to follow guidelines when designing models and tables

Comment: @Mjh Oh thanks a lot. What I learned is that table just like a phonebook. If the book is thick. Then it's hard to find a specific phonenumber. If you add a index to say where that the number from here is start with 0,1,2... . It will be easier to find. Or separate to each book will make the same trick. But now I know it's wrong.

Comment: Database internals are designed exactly like you described, but imagine that every phone book is put into the same box. Is it easier to find data if you look in 1 book, or if you have to look in each book in the box? What you had in mind is not wrong, it's completely true except the part where creating multiple tables helps with performance.

Answer (score 0):

If I were u, use relation TABLE like below

member

```
idx | user_id | user_name
  1 |       1 |       Ted
  2 |       2 |      John
  3 |       3 |      Jane
  4 |       4 |       Tom
           .
           .
           .
```

member_relation

```
idx | master_id |   user_id
  1 |         1 |         2
  2 |         2 |         1
  3 |         3 |         1
  4 |         4 |         1
           .
           .
           .
```

if you want to select jane(who's id is 3)'s user

```
SELECT a.user_id, b.user_name
FROM member_relation a
LEFT JOIN member b
ON b.user_id=a.user_id
AND a.master_id=3
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But it's not what I want. And in your case a.master_id 2,3,4 user_name would be Ted, I think.